# Sending Anonymous Mail From Website or Similar Solution

Tags: wordpress

I am a bit unfamiliar with web coding. So I am designing my webpages with existing wordpress plugins mostly. Now I need a solution for a small project, and I think that it must be very easy to do it for you especially.

Briefly I want my visitors to enter my website and send customized mails to their friends within my website without giving their contact information or their mail address. Mail recipient must see my site mail only.

For instance I am already in my website. I will fill a contact form like below.

TO: Recipient's mail address

MESSAGE: Customized message of visitors. Sample: "Hey buddy, you're such an awesome boy."

The trick here is to send an anonymous mail to friends with a customized message. And mail recipients will see my site's mail address.

Comment: Which plugin are you going to use for generating the form ? Do you mind creating a form in pure HTML code ??

Answer (score 0):

As you are not much familiar with web coding, try to use "Contact Form 7" plugin for wordpress ( it is free ) and set up a contac form.
http://contactform7.com/

In the form, use following code
[email visitor-email]

and then in the "To" section of the mail, just use
[visitor-email]

That would do the job easily

Comment: Thank you so much my friend. I am very sorry about for this dummy quiestion :)

Solved

Comment: I'm glad you solved your question. Please be kind enough to select my answer as the best answer :)

Comment: That will help other users to easily find the answer too.